# Polymer 2 : component doesn't render

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to create a Polymer element using the CLI. My component is really simple but the demo is blank.

It was working and I can't figure out what I've changed. After searching around the internet I think the problem is a wrong path or a wrong name (case sensitivity ?).

But I haven't found anything.

There isn't any error in the console and since I don't really know what code to link here, I've created a repo to share this little element.

The code is very little. I think sharing the 'hole' element is the easiest way.

repo : https://gitlab.com/mildful/test-polymer.git

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `super.ready()` in your `ready` callback.

This is required because the `Polymer.Element` declares a `ready` function to initialise the elements template and data system. As you are overriding this function, you need to call the super class function to initialise your element.

See the [info](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#one-time-initialization) on initialisation.

Without `super.ready()`

[image: Before]

With call to `super.ready()`

[image: After]

I also noticed that in your `handleClick` function, you have mis-typed the function you wish to call.

Comment: Haha so simple. Thanks a lot.